# Issue with OpenTok with Video Source as Canvas Video Track - Google Chrome 66

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, opentok

https://opentok.github.io/opentok-web-samples/Stream-Filter/

Hi,

We are facing this issue with OpenTok after the latest release of Chrome 66. The publisher is lagging a lot if supplied the video input as Canvas Video Track. Above link is what OpenTok has provided with a sample.

Everything including canvas video output works fine until we initialize the OpenTok Publisher.

As soon as we initiate the OpenTok supplying the `videoSource` as `canvasElement.captureStream(25).getVideoTracks()[0]`
after this even the Canvas starts to show delays in rendering screens.

This issue has started with the latest release of Google Chrome 66 and is not reproducible in Firefox.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welche to Stackoverflow. Could you please include [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what you tried already to address the issue?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to open an issue on chromium bug tracker. Not sure what we will be able to give you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [issue with Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=824752). Apparently it is fixed in Chrome 68. Can you try updating to Canary and see whether you still see the issue? If you do then please update the bug with details.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=824752